# Directs flights from Oman to Southern Iran

Tags: air-travel, iran, middle-east, oman

I will be travelling to Oman this summer. I researched ways of getting to Southern Iran (Bandar Abbas, Qeshm, Kish) from there and found out that supposedly, there is ([or used to be?](https://www.airportia.com/flights/y97191/muscat/bandar_abbas/)) Kish Airline flight Y97191 which connects Muscat and Bandar Abbas every Monday. However, I was not able to find any available dates this August. Their English homepage refers to the Persian version for any booking requests (and this does not seem to work too well using Google Translate) and so far, my email inquiries remain unanswered too.

[image: Kish Airline flight schedule]

Does anyone have any information on this route? Is it still serviced?

Comment: Probably want to reduce to one question per post as per the [help], or people are going to close-vote it.  Incidentally I flew from Tehran to Abu Dhabi to Muscat on Emirates, was pretty easy.

Comment: Good point! I created a separate question for the ferry part: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115413/ferry-from-khasab-to-qeshm

Comment: Your own link says the flight last operated on 23rd October 2017 so I'd assume that perticular route number longer exists

Comment: Not necessarily. It could be a seasonal flight. Also, it's still on Kish Airline's homepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**
Our alternative solution is to fly to Shiraz instead and make our way South from there. Omanian budget carrier [Salam Air](https://salamair.com/) serves the connection [three times a week (Tuesday, Friday and Sunday)](http://timesofoman.com/article/136459).

---

My best bet for a direct flight to Bandar Abbas from Muscat was [Kish Airline](https://www.kishairlines.ir/).

I tried to call Kish Airline's offices but to no avail (I was using SkypeOut). I also sent them multiple e-mails and faxes which all remained unanswered. However, some of my Iranian friends managed to get in touch with them. Apparently, the airline's Muscat-Bandar Abbas flight is not yet available this year and anyways it will be connecting via Kish. There is no direct flight.

On top of that, I'm afraid it could be quite a challenge to book these flights online. I spent hours with Kish Airline's Persian booking page (and Google Translate and a Persian calendar) but couldn't find any flight for any destination on any date. If someone was to pass this challenge I assume the next one would be to find a way to pay for your ticket. Foreign credit cards are usually not accepted in Iran.

I think the only reasonable chance is to go through an Iranian travel agency or some other contact in the country or show up in person if that's an option.

Any further details are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into *KishAirlines* flight schedule and apparently they have direct flights from Muscat to Kish, Shiraz and Chabahar.

Unfortunately, Iranian airlines, especially those smaller ones like KishAirlines, remain financially disconnected from outside the country which makes it impossible to reserve a ticket online (even their SSL certificate is expired!). Anyway, my only recommendation is to call them directly instead of sending email. Maybe you can start with their international office in Dubai? You can find their numbers [here](http://en.kishairlines.ir/sale-office/world/).

Comment: Thank you! That would've been my next try actually. I'll update any results here.