# Ferry from Khasab to Qeshm

Tags: ferries, uae, iran, oman

What is the status of the ferry route from [Khasab, Oman to Qeshm, Iran](https://www.directferries.com/khasab_qeshm_ferry.htm)? It looks like it has been suspended. Does anyone know whether this is temporary or permanent? Also, are there any other ways to cross into Iran from Oman or the UAE without flying?

Answer (score 1):

Despite [announcement in 2016 by National Ferries Company](https://www.muscatdaily.com/Archive/Oman/Visa-free-ferry-service-from-Khasab-to-Qeshm-Island-to-be-launched-soon-4l0a) that it planned to launch ferry service (visa free) between Muscat and Iran, routes are not operational.

Currently, the only [service it offers](http://www.nfc.om/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=88&Itemid=496) beyond Oman is to the United Arab Emirates (Dibba).

Excluding air, you would be left with ground transportation for the overland journey of roughly 2500km (and navigate the visa rules for multiple countries depending on route and other factors, e.g., current politics, your nationality).